# Sahabi who got sick after reading a surah

Tags: salat, source-identification, sahaba, surah

There was a sahabi who got very ill after he read a Surah I want to know the name of the Sahabi the name of the Surah too I don’t intent to do anything wrong it’s just a quiz I was asked I wonder what is the answer to it jazakallah

Comment: Welcome to Islam SE. Questions are expected to be specific, on topic, and with some research done prior to asking. Please refer to [ask], and take a [tour] in our [help]. I am not aware of any companion who was taken ill after reading a *surah* in the Qur'an.

Comment: I have never heard of such a story. Are you sure it's real?

Comment: Yes i am sure it’s real just a tip he got sick for 3 weeks I am trying to research on this but still no answer

Comment: Was it really a sahabi? Was it really a whole surah or just a verse?

Answer (score 2):

One very weak narration I came across is this mentioned in tafsir ibn Kathir:

> Al-Hafiz Abu Bakr Ibn Abi Ad-Dunya recorded that Ja'far bin Zayd Al-'Abdi said, "One night, in Al-Madinah, '**Umar** went out investigating the welfare of Muslims and passed by the house of a man who was standing in voluntary prayer. 'Umar stood quietly, listening to his recitation; the man was reciting,
> (By At-Tur -surah 52-), until he reached the Ayah,
> (Verily, the torment of your Lord will surely come to pass. There is none that can avert it. ([52:7-8](http://legacy.quran.com/52/7-8))) 'Umar said, "By the Lord of the Ka'bah, this is a true vow." 'Umar dismounted his donkey and sat next to a wall for a while. He then went back to his house and **fell ill for a month**. During his illness, the people would visit him, not knowing what caused his illness." May Allah be pleased with 'Umar. (Source: [qtafsir](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-At-tur/Allah-swears-that-the-Coming-o---))

in this quote for whatever reasons the authors of qtafsir didn't display the full narrator chain of [ibn abi ad-Dunya's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Abi_al-Dunya) narration which is quoted [here](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=1774&bk_no=49&flag=1) in tafsir ibn Kathir beside a second narration. Salih al-Murri who has transmitted the word of Ja'far bin Zayd Al-'Abdi is considered as a weak narrator.

The second narration speaks about an illness of around twenty days. And again it was referred to 'Omar ibn al-Khattab, but doesn't seem to be authentic.